# stuck on the if on Rock, paper, scissors

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding I have to do this rock paper scissors but can't find my error it still show me the else result each time.
Any help are welcome

```
// Get the computer choice
function getComputerChoice() {
    "use strict";
    const computerPlay = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    if (computerPlay === 1){
        return("rock")
    }
    else if(computerPlay === 2){
        return ("paper")
    }
    else {
        return ("scissors")
    }
}

// Get the user choice
function getUserChoice(){
    prompt("Please enter 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors': ").toLowerCase();
}

// Play a round
function playRound(){
    let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    let playerSelection = getUserChoice();
    if (computerSelection === playerSelection){
        console.log("Game is a Tie")
    }  
    else if (computerSelection == 'paper' && playerSelection == 'rock'){
        console.log("Computer Win")
    }
    else if (computerSelection == 'rock' && playerSelection == 'scissors'){
        console.log("Computer Win")
    }
    else if (computerSelection == 'scissors' && playerSelection == 'paper'){
        console.log("Computer Win")
    }
    else {
        console.log("User Win")
    }   
}

// Play Game function
function playGame(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        playRound()
    }
}

playGame()
```

I try the if seems it miss something to run correctly.

Comment: try adding a return statement for this bit so the value the user submits is returned back into your comparison logic `return prompt("Please enter 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors': ").toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You've missed the `return` keyword from the `getUserChoice` method.

```js
function getUserChoice(){
    return prompt("Please enter 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors': ").toLowerCase();
}
```